# Import external library to Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I just installed Pycharm, I tried to install Matplotlib using preferences->project interpreter, but I am getting an error. 
So I have used the terminal to install it: sudo pip install matplotlib. The installation was successful but I don't know how to import that to pycharm.

Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed matplotlib to the Python interpreter assigned to your project there is nothing else you have to do. Go to `Preferences -> Project Interpreter` and check if matplotlib is there. It should be.

Edit: Here is a visual guide to where exactly it is:
[image]

Comment: File, Edit, View, Navigate, Code, Refactor, Run, Tools, VCS, Window, Help.  Where is Preferences?  I see File --> Settings, but nothing that looks like `Project Interpreter`.

Comment: @zipzit I edited my answer with a picture! I hope that helps. You can open the settings by either going File -> Settings or pressing the combo Ctrl+Alt+S.

Comment: thx.. I figured it out.  From the top menu:  `File --> Settings --> find the project --> Project Interpreter --> Plus Sign on far right (to add new packages...)`